# Is Flash programming good for GUI prototyping?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, adobe

I used to think that Flash was a program for designers or just for web purposes, but now i am working in rapid prototyping for GUI and i am trying to learn some flash just to evaluate as solution for this kind of projects.
I found very useful some graphical capabilities, like combine graphics and video together, modify pixels, good interaction with user input...

what do you think? is flash good solution? or is limited because his web/designer origin?

br.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. In fact, Flash is one of the worst platforms for GUI out there. You are not looking at rapid prototyping at *all* using Flash.

If you want to do rapid prototypes of GUIs with an Adobe product, use [Flex](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/) instead.

If you want to do *better* GUI prototyping, use Silverlight and [Expression Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Blend_Overview.aspx).

Comment: about Flex, yes, i also thinking about that solution, i thought quite similar to flash, isnt?

about expression, i will take a look, seems that it's popular choice too.

Thanks

Comment: Flex is basically Flash for programmers. It has a suite of controls that can be used to build GUIs. With raw Flash, you're usually rolling these controls yourself. Again, and again, and again.

Comment: I question if you know Flash well at all. Flash offers great flexibility, especially when creating non standard controls and is very simple to do so. You can then export as a SWC and reuse them easily. Flex also has some nice inbuilt controls and handles changing window sizes for you nicely but is a bit more rigid. Silverlight and Expression Blend sound like they could be nice as well.

Comment: @Allan: Flash is good for graphics, yes; you can do lots of great wonderful things for it. But graphics is not GUI, and Flash outright sucks for GUI **prototyping**. You have to do everything custom, and that takes time, and time is something you don't want to spend when you're prototyping. Silverlight, on the other hand, is more analogous to Flex in that it's as capable as Flash (in many ways moreso, IMO) while still being easy to build and manipulate.

Comment: for sure, if your designing a standard interface using Silverlight/Flex is better. My comment was more in reflection that you said Flash is one of the worst platforms. It's certainly better than say Java for GUI prototyping. Also Flash is fantastic for unique interfaces, as long as you are capable with design tools then you can create unique mock up interfaces quickly. However Flash Catalyst is shaping up to be a great tool thats designed specifically for rapid interface development and is worth a look http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashcatalyst/

Answer (score 2):

Flash is not limited for GUI possibilities because you can create custom controls with vector graphics.

You have a blank slate with Flash to create as complex a GUI as you desire. But if you are prototyping for Windows use Visual Studio to drag and drop or numerous open source tools for UNIX and MAC GUI drag and drop or just use an image creation tool.

In short, Flash could be a good tool to prototype if you are creating highly customized interfaces. Otherwise, no. There are easier UI development tools out there for standardized stuff.

Comment: the point is that basically i need to design non-computer GUI, i.e. for consumer electronics product, that used to have completely diferent control (like butons, sliders and so) from PC or mac world, that's why finally i reach flash.

Comment: Flash is actually great for [non-standard] UI component prototyping.  Grab the Flex SDK, bypass all the mxml stuff, work in pure AS3, and you've got a nice platform for UI experimentation.  There are some nice source examples available here:

http://www.betterthanflex.com/?cat=3

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ability to use Expression Studio from Microsoft (I believe it's part of the Blend product), there's a prototyping tool for Silverlight/WPF that could get you going pretty well.

Comment: Minor nitpick, but it's the other way around: Expression Blend is part of Expression Studio suite. =)

Answer (score 0):

It depends the level of details your prototypes should represent. I mean, if you are prototyping very high fidelity GUI which, for instance, then will have to be built eventually in C++, Flash (without Flex SDK) could be a good solution (lot of freedom for customization and faster/easier then C++ to write). If your prototypes can be pretty rough, a solution like Flex or, even better, Flash Catalyst can be better.